# If current date is after page date - remove page?

Tags: php, date, range

I was wondering if there is a way for you to use PHP to remove content according to the date?  I have a page which lists events within a date range and I want it to remove Events that have passed.

```
I.e. 
If start date is before current date = remove event
If start date is after current date = keep event 
If start date is equal to current date = highlight event.
```

Comment: Are you using a database? If you are not, you should.

Answer (score 0):

where are you getting those events from?
is it from database.
and is the start date is stored in database.

if that is there in database.then you have to write code in php according to the format you are saving in database.

you can use php date() function to do this

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add some SQL that deletes (or archives) events where the date has passed.  I assume this information is in a database.

Or you can simply use the if statement so if the start date < current date don't display.

If you're using a database just select the events that are in the future.

Answer (score 0):

maybe some logic like:

```
//psudeocode
    //you could also use a foreach() if you are working with an array()
    //start date greater then or equal to current date
    if ($start_date >= $cur_date){

         //do some stuf with the events

            if ($start_date == $cur_date) {
                //add hilighting
        }
    //else sart date is less then current date unset/delete/toss out
    } else {
        unset $event['old event'];

    }
```